# Is it possible to add platformviews from host iOS app to flutter module view without converting into a plugin?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-platform-channel

Most of the examples I see for platform views are either a standalone flutter app or via a flutter plugin like google maps/ web view. Where as in my case I am adding a flutter module to my iOS project. Is there a way to include platform views from my host iOS app in flutter module view code. I am following the guide from [here](https://60devs.com/how-to-add-native-code-to-flutter-app-using-platform-views-ios.html) :

But is confused at the following piece of code :

```
self.registrar(forPlugin: "Runner").register(fuelFactory, withId: "webview")
```

Because right now I am calling registrar for plugin “Runner”, since the platform views are in the host app itself and not  a plugin. What should be done here ?

```
        let testFactory = TestFlutterViewFactory(controller: flutterVC)
        self.registrar(forPlugin: "Runner").register(testFactory, withId: "webview")
        flutterVC.setInitialRoute("/")
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self.flutterEngine!)
        self.window?.rootViewController = flutterVC
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(unregistered_view_type, trying to create a view with an unregistered type, unregistered view type: 'webview’)
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No. I ended up writing a plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call registrar on flutter engine, everything else is fine

```
self.flutterEngine?.registrar(forPlugin: "Runner").register(testFactory, withId: "webview")
```